# How to get multiple slider

Tags: html, css

I want to have automatic multiple sliders and they should be side by side, each sliding in different periods of time.

I am a beginner coder and tried to make this work by trying myself and searching for solutions but nothing works, it would be great if i got the code how to do it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you get multiple automatic slideshows on one page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58455922/how-do-you-get-multiple-automatic-slideshows-on-one-page)

Answer (score 0):

If you add bootstrap to your code you can use this:

```html
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Add the desired picture's location to img tag's src attribute and it will automaticly start to slide.

Note: To add bootstrap check this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/